# Facebook 'Get Started' Button not showing up anymore in my chatbot

Tags: facebook-graph-api, chatbot, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I'm not able to see 'Get Started' button in my messenger bot conversation.

But it DID appear. And for some unknown reasons, it disappeared yesterday.

I've already made this request :

`POST https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?fields=get_started&access_token=XXX`

```
{ 
  "get_started":{
     "payload":"getstarted"
   }
}
```

And checked :

`GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?fields=get_started&access_token=XXX`

Result :

```
 {
    "data": [
        {
            "get_started": {
                "payload": "getstarted"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to delete the conversation both on facebook web UI, messenger web UI and iOS app.

I am administrator of that app.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please open a bug report on this so it can be investigated:

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/

Comment: v2.6 graph api is deprecated, try newer api version - if doesn't work, report an issue as advised above

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys but, for some reasons, the button came back ... Don't know why ...